# How to programatically resize image and respect aspect ratio when saving a node

Tags: 7, media

I was wondering if there is an api call that lets me resize an image and respect the aspect ratio.  Right now I am using `image_resize` to successfully resize an image to a given width and height but it ignores aspect ratio and distorts the images.  Is there an api call that will allow me to do this and maintain original aspect ratio?

Comment: Do you explain the situation for needing to resize images *on save* rather than using image styles to resize *on display*?

Comment: @MPD.  Yes that is a good point.  Your method is what was suggested to me by a coworker, I just thought it would be simpler to resize it when saved opposed to having it themed each time it is outputted.  I am going to go with your way though, ty

Comment: The image won't be rescaled each time it gets viewed.  The derivative image gets saved to the filesystem for future use.  Bypassing the theme system generally causes problems at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`image_scale()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_scale/7) will do this if you just provide a width or a height rather than both.

Answer (score 1):

This is again a case where using code seems to only come up for the sake of it. This doesn't even involve the use of a module : everything needed is in core and manageable via the UI :

Go to `admin/config/media/image-styles/list` (provided the Image module is enabled), choose a style or create one and you can then use it in Views or in `admin/structure/types/manage/your_ct/display`.